# I lost my files under the libraries Music, Pictures and Videos after doing a windows refresh.How can I get them back?

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery, windows-8-refresh

When I did a Windows refresh, I lost my files under the libraries Music, Pictures and Videos. How can I get them back? I am using Windows 8. I have my files in the library Documents, also other files are not missing.

Comment: My operating system is windows 8

Comment: What exactly did you mean by windows refresh? Did you mean reinstall?

Comment: @Akshay - File recovery software of your choice is your only chance.  If you have done any significant writting of data on the same HDD the data is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a "Windows.old" directory ?
\windows.old\users\YOUROLDNAME\  find your lost stuff accordingly named
I don't do MS refreshes preferring restoring images, advice that isn't helping you at this moment.
Assuming you've enabled view hidden files, look for a \Windows.old directory, whether the refresh process is or isn't supposed to preserve your old settings, it's dangerous to presume anything about Windows.

If you've determined the Windows.old directory is't there AND You fear those files are deleted, turn off your computer right now since its drive activity is diminshing the chances of undeleting your lsot files.

You'll have an entirely new adventure of undeleting to undertake, and you'll need desk side help if those files are irreplaceable.